# Base condition in merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort and I'm having trouble implementing the base condition.

I have a function `merge` which takes in two sorted arrays and returns a merged array.

```
int[] merge(int[] a , int[] b)
```

Now my merge sort routine is as below

```
private static int[] mergeSort(int[] a, int low , int high)
{
    int mid = (low + high)  /2;
    if (low  < high)
    {
        return  merge( mergeSort(a,low, mid-1), mergeSort(a, mid , high));
    }
    return //return what ?
}
```

What is the base condition here? What is the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 2):

Base condition is when you have single element list `a`, which by definition is already sorted. Just return it.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting method has two return conditions:

- base condition - the array has only a single item
- merged condition - two sorted arrays have been merged

The merge method should take in two sorted arrays and return a single sorted array.

```
public int[] sort(int[] input){
  int mid = input.length/2;
  if(input.length > 1){
    // create and populate left and right arrays to merge
    // left  => input[0   > mid-1]
    // right => input[mid > input.length]
    return merge(sort(left), sort(right));
  }
  return input;
}

public int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right){
  // your merge logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply return `a` since it's already sorted (it contains at most one element).